# Need Help with a mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have 2 table 
first table. employee( empid- primary key ,empname) 
eg: employee table

```
1 john 

2 martyn 

3 davis
```

second table documents(empid,documentname) 
eg :

```
1 address.doc 

1 worksheet.doc 

1 salaryslip.doc 

3 address.doc
```

each employee have only one entry in employee table 
but in document table , zero or more entries are inserted for each employee.

i want to write a query that gives an output shown in below

```
empid empname documentflag 
1 john true 
2 martyn null 
3 davis true
```

that is, if documents table have at least one entry for an employee ,then set corresponding document flag is true. otherwise set document value as null. 
is there any efficient way using joins.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You could try a combination of UPDATE and IF NOT NULL ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a `LEFT JOIN` to include the documents table, a `GROUP BY` so that you only get 1 employee per row, and an `IF()` construct to output the values you want for documentflag.

```
SELECT e.empid, e.empname, IF(d.empid IS NULL, NULL, TRUE) `documentflag`
FROM employee e
LEFT JOIN documents d ON (d.empid = e.empid)
GROUP BY e.empid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    empid, 
    empname,
    documentFlag
FROM employee emp 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(SELECT doc.empid, count(doc.empid)as documentFlag
 FROM documents doc Group by empid) X
ON emp.empid = X.empid
```